# Android connecting to a .NET application and sending text

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I have a C# [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) application listening on a specific port for data (SocketServer).

Using Android, I would like to connect to that SocketServer and send text data to it. I do not know where to get started - sample code would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at *[TCP .NET/C# Server with Java client?](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/595908-tcp-netc-server-with-java-client/)*.

Other than that, you could always recode your server into a REST service, and then anything can communicate with it. But I know this isn't a good answer as I'm sure you don't want to recode the server.